# How to list file descriptors open by my application, or at least count them?

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

My application is exhausting the file descriptor limit. I don't understand which part does this and why, so I need a way to profile / visualize the issue. I want to list all open entries (as file system paths), or at least get the total count of descriptors open by my process. I want to implement it as a function inside my process printing this debug info so that I could insert it in various places.

There is [lsof](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/linux-lsof-command) command that prints this info by PID, but is there a simpler, programmatic way to do this in C or C++?

Comment: Are you against solution such as using `popen( "lsof" ...);` and so on?

Comment: @Cubo78, if that's what it takes then that's what I'll have to do, but it's a crutch of sorts. If there is a direct API I'd rather use that.

Comment: There’s no standard API.  Note that `popen()` will fail if there are no file descriptors available.  Getting names will be tricky; there isn’t a simple mechanism to map a file descriptor to a file name (and not all file descriptors are associated with a named file — think pipes). Consider preemptively opening one or two file descriptors at startup which you can then close when you detect problems.  You can step through numbers 0 through 255 (or any other suitable upper limit) and use `fstat()` to identify information about each file descriptor, but that won’t get you the file name.

Answer (score 0):

You could list the open descriptors by checking the files in

`/proc/[process_pid]/fd/`

That should be easy to do it in C.

Comment: Ha! I cannot list entries in a directory because `opendir()` barks "errno 24 (Too many open files)"!

Comment: What about writing and using open function that would store the max fd or the array of [fd - path] values each time you open a file?

Comment: Actually the files in there are just symlinks to to the actual files. You can try to read out the file using readlink() function. Also instead of opening thedir you can try a for loop : for ( i = 3 ; i < max_fd; i ++) { if file exists readlink(...) } 

Loop starts from 3 since first 3 are stdin, stdout, stderr